# Python Selenium loop through divs with same class name under a div id

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Pardon me, I am really new to using python selenium library but i am in dire need of help.

I have the following html:

[image]

I would like to loop through all the divs under "search-results" and get the text contents and append to a list by indexes. Here is what I have so far:

```
o = []
for content in driver.find_elements_by_id('search-results'):
    o.append(content.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"]').text)
```

While the following snippet works but it only provides me one out of ten result, only giving me the first result. Can not figure out how i can get all the results and have the texts as list within a list (or even dict).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
o = []
for content in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#search-results div.ng-star-inserted"):
    o.append(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

***you can try like this :***

```
o = []
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[tabindex]")
    
for content in search:
    o.append(content)
```